How to make an entire section as a conjecture?
I was writing a research paper and solved a problem inside it. To solve the problem for a specific case, I need to assume something to be true (I'm now sure about that) and then write a set of proofs based on that assumption.
This specific case is going to be in a separate section. My question is, how can I write such a thing? Does the entire section must be assumed as a conjecture? can I call results from an unknown (true or false) something as Theorem or Lemma?
I am having a problem with writing this section.

What field is this about?

@Buffy Computer science and Algorithms

Note that "conjecture" does not seem like the appropriate word here. A "conjecture" is something that you think should be true but that you don't how to prove. This is not your situation here. I wonder if you are conflating the words "assumption" and "conjecture".

@AdamPřenosil Yes you are right. I need to prove based on  something I don't know whether it is T or F. Then It is not a conjecture at all.

@MamaD: reread Adam’s comment.

@Aruralreader Yes I did. I was entirely wrong about the meaning of conjecture.

A conjecture is different from an assumption. A conjecture is something that can be (in theory) proven true or false. An assumption is just a condition under which something else can be (again, in theory) proven true.
What you seem to have is an assumption. If this assumption holds then you can prove something follows from it.
Of course, it could be both. "We think that X is true but don't have a proof (conjecture). If it is true then Y must also be true (assumption: If X then Y).
If your statement as a conjecture is proven false, then your proof of Y breaks down but doesn't disprove Y.
So, in section A you start with "We conjecture that the following holds...". Then section B starts "If the conjecture in A is true then...".
You can label A as a conjecture or not in the title as you choose. If you have any evidence for X then you should probably present it.

You have essentially proven an implication of the form "A implies B." Here, A is the assumption you have made. There is nothing wrong with writing your results like that as implications for which you do not know the veracity of the antecedent. In set theory, where one often uses assumptions that are provably independent of the theory, it is quite usual to write results like that ("Under
CH, the continuum is not a real-valued measurable cardinal").

Is it good to title the section as conjecture or something like this?

MamaD, not "conjecture", but "assumption", as @Buffy has noted. At least in U.S. English.
